# Nice way to add errors to Bacon EventStream?

Tags: frp, bacon.js

I've tried to find a good solution for adding errors to an **bacon.js** EventStream - and propagating them. All this because I wan't to handle the errors later possibly at multiple clients. I've found a hack with flatMap but it's a ... hack:

```
var streamWithPossibleProblems = bus.flatMap(function(v) {
    if (v == "problem") {
        return Bacon.sequentially(0, [new Bacon.Error("Error to be reported later")])
    }
    return v
});
```

Comment: Why the `Bacon.sequentially(0, `?

Comment: I thought (mistakenly) that I need to return an EventStream here but it's enough to return a raw Bacon.Error it seems.

Comment: Oh, that would be totally reasonable. But I wondered why you used `sequentially`, and sent a `0`? Just do `return Bacon.once(new Bacon.Error("fail"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just return the [`Bacon.Error`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#errors) directly from `flatMap`:

```
var streamWithPossibleProblems = bus.flatMap(function(v) {
    if (v == "problem") {
        return new Bacon.Error("Error to be reported later")
    }
    return v
});
```

Comment: It really is better and also mentioned in the bacon.js readme - this must be the canonical answer then.